# AngularJS - series of user prompts that store value in an object

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, prompt

I have an [angular app](https://mp-computer-club.firebaseapp.com/) with an interface that resembles a "command line", where the user can type in commands to navigate the site. When the user types "sign-up", I would like to ask the user a series of questions (ex. what is their name, email, etc), and for each question, they type in the command line to submit the data. Seems simple enough, but I can't figure out the best way to execute this (haha, get it? execute? okay...)

Anyway here's some pseudo-code that explains what I need to happen:

HTML:

```
<div id="cli">
    <p ng-repeat="message in output">{{message}}</p>

    <form ng-submit="execute()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input">
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

app.controller("CommandCtrl", function($scope) {

```
    var output = {},

    prompts = [
        {
            message: "What's your name?",
            responseType: "string",
            value: "name"
        },
        {
            message: "What's your email?",
            responseType: "email",
            value: "email"
        },
        {
            message: "Are you sure you want to continue? (y/n)",
            responseType: "y/n",
            value: null
        }
    ],

    programs = {
        signUp: function() {
            // What is the correct way to loop through these prompts,
            // only showing one at a time and waiting for a response?

            forEach(prompts, function(promptData) {
                prompt(promptData.message)

                .then(function(input) {
                    if (validate(input, promptData.value)) {
                        output[promptData.message] = input;

                        goToNextArrayItem();
                    } else {
                        // The input was invalid, tell the user and ask for the data again
                        tryItAgain();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.execute = function() {
        var input = $scope.input;

        if (input == 'sign-up') {
            programs.signUp();
        }

        $scope.$broadcast("recievedInput", input);
    }

    function prompt(message) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            writeLine(message);

            $scope.$on("recievedInput", function(input) {
                resolve(message);
            });
        });
    }

    function writeLine(message) {
        $scope.output.push(message);
    }

    function validate(input, dataType) {
        switch (dataType) {
            case: 'string':
                return typeof input == 'string';
                break;

            case 'email':
                // Hypothetical email validation function
                return validateEmail(dataType);
                break;

            ....

            default:
                .....
        }
    }
});
```

Basically I need to loop through the prompts, run the prompt() function for each one (which should return a promise when the user enters something). I need to be able to take the input from the user for each prompt and save it in the output object, as well as be able to "continue" to the next prompt or "go back" to the previous one. Is there any good way to loop through promises in angular?

Comment: Why don't you just write code instead of pseudo-code? Also, there doesn't seem to be a question here other than a presumed request to write actual code for you. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, so that's out...

Comment: I guess I haven't really finished my question, give me one minute. Most of it is real code, just the parts that I don't know how to do are "pseudo" code